# place a popup in tinymce after button click

Tags: tinymce

I added a button to the tinymce editor (version 4.x) and when the user clicks on it it opens a popup to set options. I would like to have this popup open next to the button but I can't find how to get the coordinates of the button.

The function called by the button has an "editor" instance which contains a "buttons" attribute, but no useful information in there for placement.

I could use the element containing the editor as a reference, but is there a better way?